# Allow using protocol if Self is either of two (or more) classes in swift?

Tags: swift, protocols

I was doing a protocol that I want to be usable by both UIView and UIViewController

I tried doing

```
    protocol ShowsResponse where Self: UIViewController, Self: UIView {
    ...
    }
```

but as the error shows, it interprets this that Self should be both UIViewController and UIView

is  there anything like "protocol ShowsResponse where Self: UIViewController "or" Self: UIView"

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just try write down a protocol and write extension for UIViewController and UIView...

for example

```
 extension UIView: ShowsResponse {
 ...
 }

 extension UIViewController: ShowsResponse {
 ...
 }

 protocol ShowsResponse {
 ...
 }
```

I think this should solve your problem..

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to have this one liner code, but now I'm starting to  think it would be better practice with this.